# set background image

Tags: java, android, background

I have set the background of my activity by doing:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/image">
```

What I'm doing: In my main activity it will chose whether I want image1 or image2 and then make either image1 or image 2 the background for the activity.

Thanks

Comment: What you've tried? You'll choose the image from where? Displaying that image on next activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
if(condition1)
linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
else
linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
```

In the XML,

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id = "@+id/linear"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

This will work. Based on the condition, it will set image1 or image2

Comment: :) user1330394 : Mark it as right answer if that works

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LinearLayout` method `setBackgroundResource` and give it the drawble id.